# Vaadin: Two filtered views of same container possible?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have data in a Vaadin 7 Container which must be shown in two Tree widgets.
In one of the trees a filter should be applied (not all nodes shown). In the other Tree the complete container should be shown. If a change is made in one tree (change of node parenting, change in properties), the other should reflect it.

My idea was to use the same container backing both trees, but to add a Filterable decorator to one container before adding it to the second Tree. But I couldn't find such a decorator. Did I miss it?

Is there another approach? I could have two separate containers for both tree, but then they need to exchange all modifications. How should the wiring be done for this?

PS: I already asked this question on the Vaadin forum but got no answer.